# A question about the relation between supremums of two functions that satisfy certain properties

Tags: calculus, continuity

I got this question:

Let $f, g : [a,b] \to [a,b]$ be functions that satisfy $\forall x \in [a,b], g(x) < f(x)$.

Prove or give a counter example for the following statements:
(1) If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $(a,b)$ then $sup (g(a,b)) < sup (f(a,b))$.
(2) If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ then $sup (g[a,b]) < sup (f[a,b])$.

Although (1) and (2) sounds true from an intuitive point of view I am having hard time trying to prove or find a counter example. Thanks.

Comment: Only one of the two assertions is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1): Let $f(x) = 1$ on $[0,1]$ and $g(x) = x$ on $[0,1)$ and $g(1)=0$. Then clearly $g(x)<f(x) = 1$, but 
$$
\sup_{x\in(0,1)}g(x) = 1 = \sup_{x\in(0,1)}f(x),
$$
so the statement is not true.

(2): This is true, but not so easily shown. We use the Weierstrass Extreme Value Theorem, which says that continuous functions with compact support attain their extrema. It then follows that
$$
\sup_{x\in[a,b]}g(x) = \max_{x\in[a,b]}g(x) < \max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x) = \sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x).
$$